# Display json content in php

Tags: php, json

I have this json file that I get from ebay api and I'm trying to echo it.
How can I reach specific values such as title, galleryURL, viewItemURL etc.

This is how I tried and getting error

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('ebay api url');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj-> item[0]->title;

?>
```

I placed item[0] because usualy I recieve bunch of items inside json
And this is json file

> {"findItemsIneBayStoresResponse":[{"ack":["Success"],"version":["1.13.0"],"timestamp":["2015-03-03T22:06:11.764Z"],"searchResult":[{"@count":"1","item":[{"itemId":["121579650061"],"title":["McCall's
>   9119 18\" Doll PatternCarry Case and Accessories Carry Case Doll Trunk
>   "],"globalId":["EBAY-US"],"primaryCategory":[{"categoryId":["38057"],"categoryName":["Dolls,
>   Toys,
>   Animals"]}],"galleryURL":["http://thumbs2.ebaystatic.com/m/mBpbx-hUvsUvTKYMVasM8xA/140.jpg"],"viewItemURL":["http://www.ebay.com/itm/McCalls-9119-18-Doll-PatternCarry-Case-and-Accessories-Carry-Case-Doll-Trunk-/121579650061?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0"],"paymentMethod":["PayPal"],"autoPay":["false"],"postalCode":["85260"],"location":["Scottsdale,AZ,USA"],"country":["US"],"storeInfo":[{"storeName":["Sew
>   Lovely
>   Patterns"],"storeURL":["http://stores.ebay.com/Sew-Lovely-Patterns"]}],"shippingInfo":[{"shippingServiceCost":[{"@currencyId":"USD","**value**":"0.0"}],"shippingType":["FlatDomesticCalculatedInternational"],"shipToLocations":["Worldwide"],"expeditedShipping":["false"],"oneDayShippingAvailable":["false"],"handlingTime":["1"]}],"sellingStatus":[{"currentPrice":[{"@currencyId":"USD","**value**":"21.99"}],"convertedCurrentPrice":[{"@currencyId":"USD","**value**":"21.99"}],"sellingState":["Active"],"timeLeft":["P22DT22H41M24S"]}],"listingInfo":[{"bestOfferEnabled":["false"],"buyItNowAvailable":["false"],"startTime":["2015-02-24T20:42:35.000Z"],"endTime":["2015-03-26T20:47:35.000Z"],"listingType":["StoreInventory"],"gift":["false"]}],"returnsAccepted":["true"],"galleryPlusPictureURL":["http://galleryplus.ebayimg.com/ws/web/121579650061_1_0_1.jpg"],"condition":[{"conditionId":["1000"],"conditionDisplayName":["New"]}],"isMultiVariationListing":["false"],"topRatedListing":["false"]}]}],"paginationOutput":[{"pageNumber":["1"],"entriesPerPage":["1"],"totalPages":["117"],"totalEntries":["117"]}],"itemSearchURL":["http://stores.ebay.com/Sew-Lovely-Patterns/_i.html?_saslop=1&_fss=1&LH_SpecificSeller=1&_ddo=1&_exmaitems=1&_ipg=1&_mPrRngCbx=1&_os=ST%7CD&_pgn=1&_sid=181133160&_ssn=sewlovelypatterns&_udlo=11"]}]}

Comment: you have an space between `$obj->` and  `item[0]->title`. what error are you getting? can you post the output of `print_r($obj)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a little analysis of the JSON. Just write this into a file (say `response.json`) and execute the following of the JSON.

```
cat response.json | python -mjson.tool
```

Now you can observe the full hierarchy in the JSON. Use the following to convert it into an `PHP Associative Array`.

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);    // note the 'true'
```

Once done with that, here is how you access via indexes easily:
e.g. to get the title, you need the following access

```
$obj["findItemsIneBayStoresResponse"][0]["searchResult"][0]["title"]
```

This is what I figured out by pretty printing the JSON. I would suggest you refer to the eBay API on how it structures the hierarchy of the response JSON. If you don't know how to read associative arrays, read some examples at [PHP Arrays Documentation].(http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).